# Grouping columns with same missing value patterns in R

Tags: r

Let I have such a data frame(df) with missing values(NA)

df:

```
head1    head2  head3   head4  head5
-----    -----  -----   -----  -----
65       25     12      65     76
78       5      NA      12     NA
NA       NA     12      5      51
76       32     6       94     11
67       32     NA      1      NA
```

I want to cretae a list(list1) each element consists of data frames with same NA patterns.

For this example:

- list1[1] must consist of a data frame(df1) with columns df$head1 and df$head2
- list1[2] must consist of a data frame(df2) with columns df$head3 and df$head5
- list1[3] must consist of a data frame(df3) with column df$head4

How can I create such a list using R? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

@akrun, I realized that your code works fine for data frames where NA's are not common for each column. But does not work for the below data frame.

```
df1<-data.frame(head1=c(65,78,NA,76,67),
                head2=c(25,5,NA,32,32),
                head3=c(12,12,NA,6,NA),
                head4=c(65,12,5,94,1),
                head5=c(76,NA,51,11,NA)
)



i1 <- which(is.na(df1), arr.ind=TRUE)
l1 <- unique(split(i1[,2], i1[,1]))
i2 <- c(l1, setdiff(seq_along(df1), unlist(l1)))
l2 <- lapply(i2, function(i) df1[i]) 
l2[order(sapply(l2, function(x) colnames(x)[1]))]
```

The result is:

```
[[1]]
  head1 head2 head3
1    65    25    12
2    78     5    12
3    NA    NA    NA
4    76    32     6
5    67    32    NA

[[2]]
  head3 head5
1    12    76
2    12    NA
3    NA    51
4     6    11
5    NA    NA

[[3]]
  head4
1    65
2    12
3     5
4    94
5     1

[[4]]
  head5
1    76
2    NA
3    51
4    11
5    NA
```

Comment: Ok akrun. However, It seems my first examle is not a true example. In that case, is it better to ask this new example in  different topic?

Comment: The first example seems to be simple example.  I think you can have many combinations i.e. comparing each column with many other columns would be the scenario here (unless I am not mistaken).  Yes, my solution assumed that there will be common elements.

Comment: What is the `dim` of your "data.frame"? `is.na(df1)` returns a binary variable for each column. So you could use that as a mapping to `split` columns. I.e. something like `split.default(df1, (t(is.na(df1)) %*% 2^(0:(nrow(df1) - 1L)))[, 1L])` if you have small `nrow` or a naive `split.default(df1, apply(is.na(df1) + 0L, 2, paste, collapse = ""))`

Comment: It s a big data frame with  approximatey 115,000 rows and 140 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the row/column index of NA elements with `which` and specifying the `arr.ind=TRUE`.  We `split` the "col" by "row", get the `unique` elements of index, if there are some columns missing i.e. that have no NA values, we can concatenate (`c`) that to the end of the `list`.  Then, `subset` the dataset using the index by looping over the `list` (`lapply(i2,..`), and we can `order` the output `list` ('l2') by the first column name in each `list` element.

```
i1 <- which(is.na(df1), arr.ind=TRUE)
l1 <- unique(split(i1[,2], i1[,1]))
i2 <- c(l1, setdiff(seq_along(df1), unlist(l1)))
l2 <- lapply(i2, function(i) df1[i]) 
l2[order(sapply(l2, function(x) colnames(x)[1]))]
#[[1]]
# head1 head2
#1    65    25
#2    78     5
#3    NA    NA
#4    76    32
#5    67    32

#[[2]]
#  head3 head5
#1    12    76
#2    NA    NA
#3    12    51
#4     6    11
#5    NA    NA

#[[3]]
#  head4
#1    65
#2    12
#3     5
#4    94
#5     1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot akrun. This code works very well. Very clever solution. Hope to be reach your level one day:)

Comment: @oercim Glad to know that it works for you.  I don't know what level I am, but practise everyday and you will learn a lot

Answer (score 1):

Using the indices of `NA` values in each column, you could map each column to a "character" value:

```
map = sapply(df1, function(X) paste(which(is.na(X)), collapse = ";"))
map
#head1 head2 head3 head4 head5 
#  "3"   "3" "3;5"    "" "2;5"
```

And, then, `split` the columns accordingly:

```
split.default(df1, match(map, unique(map)))
#> str(.Last.value)
#List of 4
# $ 1:'data.frame':      5 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ head1: num [1:5] 65 78 NA 76 67
#  ..$ head2: num [1:5] 25 5 NA 32 32
# $ 2:'data.frame':      5 obs. of  1 variable:
#  ..$ head3: num [1:5] 12 12 NA 6 NA
# $ 3:'data.frame':      5 obs. of  1 variable:
#  ..$ head4: num [1:5] 65 12 5 94 1
# $ 4:'data.frame':      5 obs. of  1 variable:
#  ..$ head5: num [1:5] 76 NA 51 11 NA
```

And performance seems tolerable for data of your actual size:

```
set.seed(666)
DF = as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:10), 115000 * 100, TRUE), 115000, 100))
DF = DF[, sample(ncol(DF), 140, TRUE)]

system.time({
    map = sapply(DF, function(X) paste(which(is.na(X)), collapse = ";"))  
    split.default(DF, match(map, unique(map)))
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.64    0.00    1.67
```

...unless you have ~60% `NA`s in each column:

```
set.seed(911)
DF2 = as.data.frame(replicate(100, sample(c(NA, 1:2), 115000, TRUE, c(0.6, 0.2, 0.2)), simplify = FALSE))
DF2 = DF2[, sample(ncol(DF2), 140, TRUE)]

system.time({
    map = sapply(DF2, function(X) paste(which(is.na(X)), collapse = ";"))  
    split.default(DF2, match(map, unique(map)))
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   8.70    0.09    8.99
```